# Increment and decrement version numbers

Tags: javascript, html, button, increment, decrement

I want to increment and decrement  1.2.3 in  this problem when we increase with a button after the right side value increased to 1.2.9 it should be1.3.0 and when second decimal point reaches to 1.9.9 it should change to 2.0.0 .

The same condition for decrement in a html number box  using js or html in a table.

[image]

Comment: Use a number for the value and add the dots when you display it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: when i decrement from 1.0.0  i get 9.9. instead of 0.9.9

Comment: What does `1.2.3` represent, because if it's say like a semantic version, then you could have `1.2.15`, `3.12.2` etc.  If each section is only going to go 0-9, then do what @ChrisG said and convert to number, increase, back to string with pre-zero, and then put the decimals back in.

Comment: yes  it should be like that

Comment: Should be like what?, If it's just `(0-9).(0-9).(0-9)` something as simple as `String(('1.0.0'.replaceAll('.','') | 0) -1).padStart(3,'0').split('').join('.')` will work.  The above subtracts 1 from `1.0.0.` and get `0.9.9` as suggested.

Comment: @keith i want to be in semantic version for each decimal.

Comment: and it should be in html

Comment: i need a full code so that i can work out

Comment: Well if it's full semantic, then when a number gets to 9, it's not forced to increase the next level.  eg. Your example of decreasing `1.0.0` giving `0.9.9`,  this could be `0.28.77`,  because  a major sematic version from `0.28.77` would become `1.0.0`,..  IOW: It's impossible to increase / decrease a full sematic version, because there is no logic when  `major` / `minor` / `patch` reaches it's end.  Normally when you do a sematic update, you first select what your update, `major / minor / patch`.  Worth noting `99999999999999999999999.999999999999999999.99999999999999999` is a valid version.

Comment: Convert to a string, pad with zeros to length 3, then insert the dots.

Comment: pls send in html code

Comment: for Should be like what?, If it's just (0-9).(0-9).(0-9) something as simple as String(('1.0.0'.replaceAll('.','') | 0) -1).padStart(3,'0').split('').join('.') will work. The above subtracts 1 from 1.0.0. and get 0.9.9 as suggested.                                                                                        this one i need in html

Comment: <input type="number" class="emb" value="450"  /> 
   
  <span style="position: absolute;
  left:200px; top:225px " > &#8901;</span>
  
  <span style="position: absolute;
  left:219px; top:225px " > &#8901;</span>

Comment: i used this code